# Finding a limit involving ratios of logarithms

Tags: limits, logarithms

My friends. I apologize upfront for any spelling mistakes, I'm not used to writing math in english!
I'm having trouble figuring out this limit and no calculator online I checked can show me (reasonable) steps for this.

The question tells me I have to use the ratio test. The limit I decided to call "L" is returning me "e", when it should return an "0".
Can anyone point me to where I'm making it wrong?

Thank you very much in advance! Cheers.

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{(\ln n)^n}\to\mathrm{Ratio\;test}\to\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{[\ln(n)]^n}{[\ln (n+1)]^{n+1}}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right]^n\dfrac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$$
>   $\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty} f\cdot g=\lim_{n\to\infty} f\lim_{n\to\infty} g}$,
>   $$\require{cancel}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right]^n\dfrac{1}{\ln(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right]^n\cancel{\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{\ln(n+1)}}$$
>   If the limit on the left exists, we are good to go:
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right]^n=L$$
>   $$\ln(L)=\ln\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)}\right]^n\to\mathrm{L'Hospital}\to\ln(L)=\ln\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\dfrac{1/n}{1/(n+1)}\right]^n\to\\\ln(L)=\ln\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1+\dfrac1n\right]^n\to\ln(L)=\ln e\to \boxed{L=e}$$

Comment: You can learn with a bit of effort to post mathematical expressions here.  See this [introduction to $\LaTeX$](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and its links to more detailed information.  In the meantime I'll try to convert your image to a math format.

Comment: thank you. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I converted only the part of your image that defines the limit you have a problem with.  Note that in your own writeup you "discard" a factor that does tend to zero, so perhaps you forget that when the above tends to a finite limit and the other "factor" tends to zero, the product tends to zero as well.

Comment: indeed, i'm aware of the discarded part, and that would return me 0 just fine, the point is, the limit called L I decided to work on is giving me a result different from wolfram's.

Comment: The edited post has a very different problem than the OP linked. Could you please put it right back, @hardmath ?

Comment: Note that the expression inside the square brackets is less than one (for large $n$), and raising it to a positive power gives again a value less than one.  So the limit cannot be $e$.

Comment: @DonAntonio:  I disagree.  The Question's body itself asks about the limit $L$.  The OP has engaged in a discussion about the error in finding that limit.  If you want to use the image in your Answer discussing "where the error is", feel free to do so.  It is very distracting from the essence of what they need help with, in my opinion.

Comment: @hardmath I think that this question in particular, and almost any other question, must be read from its context. To write down just a very, very little part of the question can be greatly misleading

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut:  I think (or would like to think) that you misunderstand the situation.  It has been frequently discussed on Meta that $\LaTeX$ is preferred to images for posting mathematics, and I had begun (successfully it turns out) in convincing the OP of this by posting a $\LaTeX$ formula which (if you read all the discussion here) was the place where the error occurred.  It was my effort to post a mathematical expression that got removed, so as you act as a bystander without "enough time this morning" to "translate the whole thing in LaTeX", I don't see the point of your complaint.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I look forward to discussing it over a cold drink sometime.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in applying L'Hôpital's Rule in taking the limit.

As I pointed out in a Comment earlier, you are taking a limit of a quantity which is less than $1$:

$$ L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)} \right]^n $$

We cannot directly apply L'Hôpital's Rule to a subexpression as you tried to do with the ratio inside the brackets.  The limit involves raising that quantity to a power.  You applied the derivative to both numerator and denominator *inside the bracket* and got a ratio which is *greater than* $1$, so it clearly is invalid.

One idea to correct this would be to apply the power $n$ to both numerator and denominator *before* taking a derivative, e.g.

$$ L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left[ \frac{(\ln(n))^n}{(\ln(n+1))^n} \right] $$

This doesn't seem like a great idea to pursue (too many tedious details to find the derivative with respect to $n$ when $n$ appears as an exponent).

Instead I would simply note that the ratio we've been discussing is bounded above by $1$.  So any limit it may have is less than or equal to $1$.

In fact you can go back to the point where you removed the factor $\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$ and directly argue that because:

$$ 0 \lt \left[ \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)} \right]^n \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)} \lt \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)} $$

the [Pinching Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) tells us the limit of the expression in between $0$ and $\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$ must be zero (because it is squeezed between two expressions both tending to zero).

Comment: now this is a brilliant explanation. thank you very much.

edit: so is it safe to say that this:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } {\left[ {f\left( x \right)} \right]^n} = {\left[ {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } f\left( x \right)} \right]^n}$$

is only true when 'n' is a natural number and not another function of x?

Comment: I'm actually confused again, once I used the log funcion to get the x power "down", I only used properties I thought were valid, there was no x power on the log's division, isn't this is a valid thing?

Comment: You applied l'Hopital's rule to the inside expression with that being raised to the power $n $.  I'm not seeing any taking a logarithm to get the power "down".  You have a limit using $n$ as the variable, not $x$.  So it's hard to guess what you are asking about being valid.

Comment: I'm sorry. My mistake, I was referring to a different attempt I hadn't even posted. Like this:

$$\eqalign{
  & \ln \left( L \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \ln {\rm{ }}{\left[ {{{\ln \left( n \right)} \over {\ln \left( {n + 1} \right)}}} \right]^n}  \cr 
  & \ln \left( L \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } n\ln {\rm{ }}\left[ {{{\ln \left( n \right)} \over {\ln \left( {n + 1} \right)}}} \right] \cr} $$

Following this way, I end up with "e" as result, the same way.

Comment: It's an idea worth exploring, but note that taking the logarithm of the expression inside the square brackets will give a negative number, in fact $\ln \ln n - \ln \ln(n+1)$.  So the limit $\ln L$ cannot be positive.

Comment: now this makes a lot of sense.
i can relax now there's a perfect explanation. thanks again

Comment: Anyway, look at you with your new ability to write math expressions!

Comment: I'm cheating, mate hahaha
Found out Mathtype lets me type as usual on it and has a copy&paste option specifically for this. =/

Sorry about all this mess.

Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the $\;n\,-$th root test better?:

$$\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\log^nn}\right|}=\frac1{\log n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

I can't understand in your work why you "erased" that $\;\frac1{\log(n+1)}\;$

Forcing the ratio test: you already had

$$\left(\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}\right)^n\cdot\frac1{\log(n+1)}$$

The rightmost factor clearly tends to zero, whereas the left one is bounded by one since the function $\;\log(x)\;$ is monotone ascending...

Comment: i'd like to use the root test, but the question tells me I have to use the ratio.

the part I left aside would be 1/log(n+1)? 

Knowing it returns 0, I just wanted to confirm I could get a finite limit on the left part.

Comment: @PedroAlonso Read what I added now. You don't need to know the left factor has a finite limit, only that it is bounded...

Comment: thank you Don Antonio for your effort and help.

I'm no advanced student, so I'd be confused about the "monotone ascending part". Isn't the 1^(infinity) part be an indetermined factor?

What's really driving me crazy is that I know some property or some passage on my solution is clearly wrong, but I can't put my finger on it since yesterday.

Comment: @PedroAlonso What is your mother language? Spanish? Maybe it would be easier for you a short explanation in spanish...

Comment: it's portuguese! I'm as used with english math as I am with spanish math, unfortunately.

Comment: @PedroAlonso Bem, isso nao importa. Anyway, since $\;1\le 0\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}\le1\;$ , we have that $\;0\le\left(\frac{\log n}{\log(n+1)}\right)^n\le1\;$ , so your expression before deleting the right factor is something bounded times something that tends to zero, and this tends to zero (you can use the squeeze theorem) .That's all.